# How to render a table of divs with JSF?

Tags: jsf-2

I need to draw a table with a column and a dynamic number of rows depending on a number of bills that I file with JSF without using an extension as PrimeFaces.

I've been looking for how to use the component `h:panelGrid` with `h:panelGroup` inside for bills without finding a solution.

welcome your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a table of divs, one way would be to use iterating tag :

**View :**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.rows}" var="row">
    <div>
         #{row.data}
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

**Bean :**

```
public List<YourObject> getRows()
{
    return this.rows;
}
```

This is only a draft, but it show you the way. If you add more informations how your data is constructed, It will be easier to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: the rows variables should be list?

Comment: @JoseAlfonso exactly, as I updated in the answer. Could also be an array.