# moving from h:datatable to Grid view

Tags: jsf, xhtml, facelets

I already used `h:datatable` to list data from a bean like:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{mybean.view}" var="o" border="1" >

                <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                    #{o.name}
                </h:column>
                              <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                    #{o.id}
                </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

But now I want to switch to using panelgrid and apply my layout, i did this like

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="myGrid" value="#{mybean.view}" var="o">
   <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="col-sm-3">
      <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="griditem">


        <h:outputText styleClass="description" value="#{o.name}" />
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and I get no result at all. Is it wrong to use a panel group and the place where assigned the value?

Comment: Where did you read an `h:panelGroup` has a value attribute and var for iteration? That just does not exists...

Comment: so which attribute should I use instead of value ?

Comment: i want the output to be divs not table tags such as tr and td

Comment: @Kukeltje many thanks I used repeat with panel group and it magically worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a table of divs with JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992698/how-to-render-a-table-of-divs-with-jsf)

Answer (score 0):

Use following sample which uses ui:repeat

```
<table>

<ui:repeat var="o" value="#{order.orderList}" varStatus="status">

    <tr>
        <td>#{o.orderNo}</td>
        <td>#{o.productName}</td>
        <td>#{o.price}</td>
        <td>#{o.qty}</td>
    </tr>

</ui:repeat>        

</table>
```